# Why is unzip in the file explorer so slow?

Tags: filemanager, unzip

I frequently unzip files which contain thousands of small text files within them.

I have noticed that when I do this in the file explorer (*right-click* → *Extract here*) it can take a long time and sometimes seems to never finish, even after waiting for minutes.

Unzipping the same file in the terminal with `unzip file.zip` always finishes in a few seconds.

What does the file explorer do differently and why does it take much longer? Why does it sometimes never finish at all? It seems very poorly done in comparison, while I would expect that it just runs the same command behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

There's more activity going on in the GUI File Explorer. For each of your "thousands of files", the File Explorer has to determine which icon to use.
Then, it has to position the icon on the screen, and set the "screen refresh" flag.
Not much additional processing for 1 file, but "thousands"?

After you've extracted these "thousands of files", if you restart your File Explorer, and then open the directory with the files, you'll notice a large delay.

Processing "thousands of files" with a GUI File Explorer just seems wrong. `perl`, for example will let one read ZIP files and access the files within the ZIP.